# case not working in sql

Tags: sql

```
select  employee_size_range_id 
from  tbl_employee_size_range 
where employee_range_values = '1 to 10'
```

in case:

```
SELECT employee_size_range_id,
       employee_range_values,
       CASE WHEN employee_range_values = '1 to 10' THEN 'employee_size_range_id'
FROM tbl_employee_size_range
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Add some sample table, and the expected result (as well formatted text.)

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for `WHERE`?

Comment: the query which is given in where clause i want to perform in 'case'

Comment: "not working" is not an adequate description. If you get an *error message*, tell us what error you get. If you get *unexpected results*, show us what results you get and what you *expected*.

Comment: select employee_size_range_id  from tbl tbl_employee_size_range whose  employee_range_values = '1 to 10'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 SELECT employee_size_range_id,employee_range_values, 
    CASE WHEN (RTRIM(LTRIM(employee_range_values)) = '1 to 10' ) 
    THEN 'employee_size_range_id' END 
 FROM tbl_employee_size_range.employee_range_values
```

Comment: select employee_size_range_id  from tbl tbl_employee_size_range whose  employee_range_values = '1 to 10'

Comment: 'SELECT employee_size_range_id,employee_range_values,
   CASE WHEN (employee_range_values = '1 to 10' ) THEN 'employee_size_range_id' END FROM tbl_employee_size_range.employee_range_values'

Comment: Is *employee_range_values* column datatype integer or varchar?

Comment: its a varchar in my case

Comment: 'SELECT employee_size_range_id,employee_range_values, CASE WHEN (RTRIM(LTRIM(employee_range_values)) = '1 to 10' ) THEN 'employee_size_range_id'  END FROM tbl_employee_size_range.employee_range_values'

Answer (score 1):

You missed `END` in case statement

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT employee_size_range_id,
   employee_range_values,
   CASE WHEN employee_range_values = '1 to 10' THEN employee_size_range_id END AS X
FROM tbl_employee_size_range.employee_range_values
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT employee_size_range_id,
       employee_range_values,
       CASE WHEN employee_range_values = '1 to 10' THEN 'employee_size_range_id' END
FROM tbl_employee_size_range